How to switch between terminals in new window in Visual Studio Code?
After you separate terminal to a new window with workbench.action.terminal.moveIntoNewWindow action, all of:

workbench.action.terminal.focusNext
workbench.action.terminal.focusNextPane
workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious
workbench.action.terminal.focusPreviousPane

are spawning new terminal in the main window. How to switch tabs of terminal in the new terminal window just created?

you can create a custom keybinding. specially for your detached terminal window.
a. in VS Code Keyboard Shortcuts settings open:

(File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts or Ctrl+K Ctrl+S)

b. search for the commands you want to remap

(e.g. workbench.action.terminal.focusNextPane)

c. right-click on the command and select

"Copy Command ID"

d. click on the keybindings.json button to open the keybindings file.
Add your custom keybindings; using the when clause to target the detached terminal window. example:
{
   "key": "ctrl+tab",
   "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNextPane",
   "when": "terminalFocus && terminalInstance.isWindowed" 
 },
 {
   "key": "ctrl+shift+tab",
   "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPreviousPane",
   "when": "terminalFocus && terminalInstance.isWindowed"
 }
 

This will use ctrl+tab and ctrl+shift+tab to cycle through terminals, but only when the focus is in a detached terminal window.
